# Word wrap not showing up in my style sheet

Tags: css, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to take care of extra long text by using the following.(I don't want to use `break-all` because it's too harsh)

```
.user_info {
       width:50px;


      h2  {
         -moz-hyphens:auto;
        -ms-hyphens:auto;
        -webkit-hyphens:auto;
        hyphens:auto;
        word-wrap:break-word;
   }
}
```

When I preview this in the Chrome inspector it does exactly what I want, but when I put it into my CSS it never shows up in the new page after I reload.

Also, in Cloud9, my IDE these don't show up the same color as other CSS does. Not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: You have some strange nesting going on there. Is that a typo or is this your actual code?

Comment: The first closing bracket is too much.

Comment: @Turnip what's wrong with the nesting?

Comment: Well you have 5 braces for a start. 5 is an uneven number :)

Comment: @Turnip sorry was typo on my end on here. not in code.

Comment: Are you using a pre-processor such as SASS or LESS? If not, you can not nest CSS.

Comment: @Turnip yea. bootstrap-sass. all other nested CSS is working fine. literally just this one block.

Comment: bootstrap-sass is not a preprocessor. It is a collection of SCSS files that can be compiled with SASS. Are you adding your above code to a `.css` file or a `.scss` file?

Comment: i'm following from rails tutorial i'm pretty sure I'm using a pre processor. file is custom.css.scss

Comment: "Pretty sure" may not be good enough. Make _absolutely_ sure! And/or, rewrite this as normal CSS just in case.

Comment: could you also post your `HTML`?

Comment: In the case the above is SCSS, can you post the relevant snippet of CSS that was generated against this?